# How do I extract 'url' and put it in a new column called Tweet_url?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract 'url' from this block of text that's in a column called 'entities' and want to put it in another column called 'Tweet_url'

> {'hashtags': [],
> 'symbols': [],
> 'user_mentions': [],
> 'urls': [],
> 'media': [{'id': 892177413194625024,
> 'id_str': '892177413194625024',
> 'indices': [139, 162],
> 'media_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DGGmoV4XsAAUL6n.jpg',
> 'media_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DGGmoV4XsAAUL6n.jpg',
> 'url': 'https://twitter.com/0Xxu71qeIV',
> 'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/0Xxu71qeIV',
> 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892177421306343426/photo/1',
> 'type': 'photo',
> 'sizes': {'large': {'w': 1407, 'h': 1600, 'resize': 'fit'},
> 'thumb': {'w': 150, 'h': 150, 'resize': 'crop'},
> 'small': {'w': 598, 'h': 680, 'resize': 'fit'},
> 'medium': {'w': 1055, 'h': 1200, 'resize': 'fit'}}}]}

I tried this but got Key error: 'media'
`df_copy['Tweet_url'] = df_copy['entities']['media'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['url'] if x else None)`

I also tried this and got the same error as above
`df_copy['Tweet_url'] = df_copy['entities']['media'].str.extract('(https?://\S+)', expand=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you need `.str` accessor to access the list/dictionary object in the column, you can do with

```py
df_copy['Tweet_url'] = df_copy['entities'].str['media'].str[0].str['url']
```